# Locking order in cursors (Oracle)

Tags: oracle, locking

I wonder if the order in which records are locked is guaranteed when I use `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` in cursors ?
For example,

```
DECLARE 
CURSOR test_cursor IS 
SELECT field1, field2 
FROM table1 
ORDER BY pk_field
FOR UPDATE OF field1;
```

When I open such a cursor, will it always lock records in the order of `pk_field` ?

From what I read so far order of locking is not guaranteed for regular `SELECT ... ORDER BY pk_field FOR UPDATE` , but I'm not sure if it's true for cursors. I'd expect it does lock in the order set in `ORDER BY` clause for cursors; however, I cannot find confirmation.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order in which individual rows will be locked is undefined and certainly not something you should rely on since it will depend on the query plan.

In general, I would expect that the rows would not be locked in order-- the optimizer would generally expect it to be more efficient to access all the data unordered and then apply the `ORDER BY`.  If there was a composite index on `pk_field, field1, field2`, I could see the optimizer potentially choosing to do an ordered scan of the index and then locking each row in the table but that seems unlikely.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Then I think `FOR UPDATE` in cursors is quite dangerous feature which may cause deadlocks...

Comment: @a1ex07 - No more dangerous than, say, an `UPDATE` statement.  It's entirely possible that if you have two sessions trying simultaneously to update the same set of rows that the two sessions would get a different query plan and that they would affect rows in a different order leading to a deadlock.  But while it's possible, it's relatively unlikely.